# What information can be gained given only a phone number?

Tags: privacy, phone

What personal information can be obtained given only a phone number?

What information is your phone number publicly (or privately, but with easy access) linked to?

Here is the way I am looking at it:

Your phone provider knows your name and physical address. Additionally, they may know your email address, your SSN, etc.

Disregarding the possibility for a breach of the phone provider's data, are individuals or organizations able to obtain this information? Do phone providers sell or distribute this information in any way?

Comment: This is **very** country- and provider-specific.

Comment: Answer to title question: Whatever information the person who answers it can be convinced to give you.

Comment: What about the "burner phone" concept popularized in TV and movies? Pre-pay with cash and no info can be gleaned. Are you asking about failures of process or the normal phone company processes? I think this question needs to be fleshed out a little more.